# How to set up project with docker and deepstream.io?

Tags: docker, deepstream.io

https://github.com/PhillippOhlandt/deepstream-turn-based-game-demo

I cloned this repo and am trying to get it up and running but think I am missing a step.

I run `npm install` inside the folder, and I have also installed docker on my mac. Then I run `docker-compose up` and it starts up. When I go to localhost nothing happens?

I don't think I fully understand what's going on here...

**UPDATE**

```
deepstream_1    |       _                     _                              _
deepstream_1    |    __| | ___  ___ _ __  ___| |_ _ __ ___  __ _ _ __ ___   (_) ___
deepstream_1    |   / _` |/ _ \/ _ \ '_ \/ __| __| '__/ _ \/ _` | '_ ` _ \  | |/ _ \
deepstream_1    |  | (_| |  __/  __/ |_) \__ \ |_| | |  __/ (_| | | | | | |_| | (_) |
deepstream_1    |   \__,_|\___|\___| .__/|___/\__|_|  \___|\__,_|_| |_| |_(_)_|\___/
deepstream_1    |                  |_|
deepstream_1    |  =========================   starting   ==========================
deepstream_1    | INFO | logger ready
deepstream_1    | INFO | deepstream version: 2.1.2
deepstream_1    | INFO | configuration file loaded from /etc/deepstream/config.yml
deepstream_1    | INFO | library directory set to: /var/lib/deepstream
deepstream_1    | INFO | messageConnector ready
deepstream_1    | INFO | storage ready
deepstream_1    | INFO | cache ready
deepstream_1    | INFO | authenticationHandler ready: file using /etc/deepstream/users.yml
deepstream_1    | INFO | permissionHandler ready: valve permissions loaded from /etc/deepstream/permissions.yml
deepstream_1    | INFO | Listening for health checks on path /health-check
deepstream_1    | CLUSTER_JOIN | jgx4b6kz-1y8u6be9n0744
deepstream_1    | INFO | Listening for websocket connections on 0.0.0.0:6020/deepstream
deepstream_1    | INFO | Deepstream started
deepstream_1    | INCOMING_CONNECTION | from undefined (172.18.0.3)
deepstream_1    | AUTH_ATTEMPT | 172.18.0.3: AREQ{"username":"backend","password":"password"}
deepstream_1    | AUTH_SUCCESSFUL | backend
gameprovider_1  | LOGIN true { username: 'backend', role: 'backend' }
deepstream_1    | S | for P:get-game-types by backend
deepstream_1    | S | for P:create-game by backend
deepstream_1    | S | for P:join-game by backend
deepstream_1    | S | for P:leave-game by backend
deepstream_1    | S | for P:turn by backend
```

Comment: "nothing happens" is not a useful error description. Check the logs, check if the containers are still running, check if a process is listening on the port ...

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game demo is working, but the creators should add a few lines of friendly manual. However, don't worry, I'll cover it for you here.

1. After running `docker-compose up` open up your browser at http://localhost:8088/
2. Enter Username: userA Password: password
3. Create a new game and note the GameID
4. Open up another browser tab at http://localhost:8088/
5. Enter Username: userB Password: password
6. Join the game by previously noted GameID and you can start playing already.

The game supports up to 4 users and in authors' defense, they created a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvSgGa5aruo), but forgot to provide some useful instructions, like what the password is.

Comment: You're the man cool guy. How did you know which port to go to was my biggest question?

Comment: ahh nevermind I found it... I should have looked harder inside the `docker-compose.yml` file